# Sorting with tie-breaking that minimizes disconinuity of a boolean field

Tags: r, performance, algorithm, stable-sort

Let `D` be a data.frame, with `D$x` containing real numbers and `D$y` containing booleans, among other fields.

The problem is to sort the rows of `D` so that `D$x` is non-decreasing, while breaking ties in a way that minimizes the number of discontinuities in the resulting `D$y`.

Is there a simple fast way to accomplish this in R?

### More Information

In a language like C I would first sort by x, then pass over the result sequentially with a 2-state FSM to iron out the discontinuities as far as possible. But in R, I expect iteration to carry unnecessary overhead if there are thousands of rows to process sequentially.

Example correct result:

```
D$x  D$y
1    FALSE
1    FALSE
1    TRUE
1    TRUE
1.2  TRUE
1.5  TRUE
1.5  FALSE
```

Example incorrect result:

```
D$x  D$y
1    TRUE
1    FALSE
1    TRUE
1    FALSE
1.2  TRUE
1.5  FALSE
1.5  TRUE
```

In the example, the correct result has 2 discontinuities while the incorrect result has 6.

**EDIT: We can assume the data is such that the density of discontinuities in the result will be low: Less than 1 discontinuity per 1000 rows, say.**

Comment: When you say minimize, do you mean in the optimization sense?  Or are is there a "good enough" result?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this in less than 2 passes, simply because you don't know where elements will end up in proximity after they're sorted.

Comment: @Ricardo If by optimization, you mean in the minimization sense, then yes :) The sort order on `D$y` should invert on those values of x where continuity stands to benefit from said inversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much faster solution than sequential iteration (if discontinuities are sparse):

```
sortForMaxContY <- function(D,initialY){
    n <- nrow(D)
    D <- D[order(D$x),]

    xChanges <- D$x[-1]!=D$x[-n]
    isLastOfXVal <- c(xChanges,T)
    rankOfXVal <- cumsum(c(T,xChanges))

    oldFinalYs <- NA
    finalYs <- D$y[isLastOfXVal]
    while(!identical(finalYs,oldFinalYs)){
        finalYOfPrecedingXVal <- c(initialY,finalYs)[rankOfXVal]
        oldFinalYs <- finalYs
        D <- D[order(D$x,xor(finalYOfPrecedingXVal,D$y)),]
        finalYs <- D$y[isLastOfXVal]
    }
    return(D)
}
```

One of `sortForMaxContY(D,T)` and `sortForMaxContY(D,F)` is the optimum, and the other usually is too, depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you perfect results, if there is an optimal rearranging of y, but otherwise will work

```
D[order(D$x, D$y), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution:

```
sortForMaxContY <- function(D,initialY){
    n <- nrow(D)

    D <- D[order(D$x),]

    x <- c(D$x,Inf)
    whichT <- c(which(D$y),n+1)
    whichF <- c(which(!D$y),n+1)

    finalOrder <- rep(0,n) # allocate space
    lastY <- initialY
    iT <- 1
    iF <- 1
    for(i in 1:n){
        wT <- whichT[iT]
        wF <- whichF[iF]
        chooseT <- sign(x[wF]-x[wT])+lastY-0.5>0
        w <- ifelse(chooseT, wT, wF)
        finalOrder[i] <- w
        lastY <- D$y[w]
        iT <- iT + chooseT
        iF <- iF + !chooseT
    }

    return(D[finalOrder,])
}
```

One of `sortForMaxContY(D,T)` and `sortForMaxContY(D,F)` is the optimum, and the other usually is too, depending on the data.

Doesn't R have a way to do this faster?